# Calling base class of a class in an assembly loaded into a seperate app domain

Tags: c#

I've been fighting with this for a few days now and can't find anything on google for this particular situation. I know what I want to do is possible because I have worked with another application that does it (Exit game Photon) Photon unfortunately will NOT run under linux and what I have so far does which is why I'm trying to "re-invent the wheel)

I have a program that loads an assembly (plugin type of thing) into a seperate App domain then pulls the interface and can run fuctions defined in the interface on the class in my assembly but my assembly class inherits from a base class that is in another assembly. I want to be able to run a fuction on the base class without having to add it to the derived class but all I get is an exception

Base Class:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class ApplicationBase : MarshalByRefObject, IApplicationBase
{
    public abstract void SetUp();
    public virtual void TearDown() { }
    public virtual void OnStopRequested() { }

    public virtual void OnServerConnectionFailed(int errorCode, string errorMessage, object state)
    {
        //Do nothing this is only for the individual servers
    }
}
```

Test Server Class:

```
public class TestServer : ApplicationBase
{
    protected readonly ILogger Log = LogManager.GetLogger("TestServer");

    public override void SetUp()
    {
        Log.Debug("Setup"); 
    }

    public override void TearDown()
    {
        Log.Debug("TearDown");
    }

    public override void OnServerConnectionFailed(int errorCode, string errorMessage, object state)
    {
    }

    public override void OnStopRequested()
    {
        Log.Debug("Stop Requested");
    }
}
```

Now I can call any of Setup, TearDown, OnStopRequested, or OnServerConnectionFailed as my plugins class overrides them. and I get the logger output.
If I put something like:

```
public void Configure(string val1, string val2)
    {
        //Initialize the values
    }
```

in the base class, after I instantiate the plugin with the following Code:

```
ApplicationPath = $"{DeployPath}\\{AppConfig.BaseDirectory}\\bin";
        if (!File.Exists(ApplicationPath + "\\" + AppConfig.Assembly + ".dll")) Console.WriteLine("ERROR {0} Not found", AppConfig.Assembly);
        AppDomainSetup adSetup = new AppDomainSetup
        {
            ApplicationBase = ApplicationPath,
            ApplicationName = AppConfig.Name,
            PrivateBinPath = ApplicationPath,
            ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
            ShadowCopyDirectories = ApplicationPath
        };
        _appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(string.Format("{0} AppDomain", AppConfig.Assembly), null, adSetup);
        _application = (IApplicationBase)_appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(AppConfig.Assembly, AppConfig.Type);
```

If i then try to call `_application.Configure("one","two");`
I get the following Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void EmpireHostRuntimeInterfaces.IApplicationBase.Configure(System.String, System.String)'.
>      at SocketServer.Program.Start()
>      at SocketServer.Program.Main(String[] args)

this is the IApplicationBase interface:

```
public interface IApplicationBase
{
    void Configure(string val1, string val2);
    void SetUp();
    void TearDown();
    void OnServerConnectionFailed(int errorCode, string errorMessage, object state);
    void OnStopRequested();
}
```

Now from what I can tell its throwing that exception because the base class defines the function and not the direved class but I'm going to eventually release this for other other people to use and I need to call the function in the base class because it needs to be transparent to the derived class (it sets up some information from the main server config to pass down to the sub application)

Anything I put in the base class I can access from my plugins derived class (for example if I put a `public string ApplicationName = "Application1"` in the base class and then call `Log.Debug(ApplicationName);` in my derived class it shows the value of whats in the base class I just can't figure out for the life of me how to call the base classes constructor with arguments

I tried passing arguments with the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap but that just threw a no constructor found exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if its the "proper" way but I figured out a way to do it by creating a serializable class call ApplicationData with the fields I need then instantiating a new ApplicationData class and adding it to the AppDomain data area wich my base class in the plugin can access

```
ApplicationData data = new ApplicationData {ApplicationName = AppConfig.Name, BinaryPath = ApplicationPath};
_appDomain.SetData("Data", data);
```

then in my base class I added a parameterless constructor:

```
protected ApplicationBase()
{
    _appData = (ApplicationData)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("Data");
}
```